# How to add extra outer space to inline svg?

Tags: css, svg, inline-svg

I have an inline svg with transparent `fill` and a dark `stroke`. When it's hoverd, I want to `fill` it with the dark color.
The problem is that when I increase the `stroke-width` to make the stoke more visible, the stroke goes out the width box of the element like in the screenshot below.
So how to give the svg element an extra space for the stroke to grow?

[image]

```css
svg {
  width: 10rem;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #222;
  stroke-width: 30;
}

svg:hover {
  fill: #222;
}
```

```html
<svg 
  viewBox="0 -28 512.00002 512" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
  <path d="m471.382812 44.578125c-26.503906-28.746094-62.871093-44.578125-102.410156-44.578125-29.554687 0-56.621094 9.34375-80.449218 27.769531-12.023438 9.300781-22.917969 20.679688-32.523438 33.960938-9.601562-13.277344-20.5-24.660157-32.527344-33.960938-23.824218-18.425781-50.890625-27.769531-80.445312-27.769531-39.539063 0-75.910156 15.832031-102.414063 44.578125-26.1875 28.410156-40.613281 67.222656-40.613281 109.292969 0 43.300781 16.136719 82.9375 50.78125 124.742187 30.992188 37.394531 75.535156 75.355469 127.117188 119.3125 17.613281 15.011719 37.578124 32.027344 58.308593 50.152344 5.476563 4.796875 12.503907 7.4375 19.792969 7.4375 7.285156 0 14.316406-2.640625 19.785156-7.429687 20.730469-18.128907 40.707032-35.152344 58.328125-50.171876 51.574219-43.949218 96.117188-81.90625 127.109375-119.304687 34.644532-41.800781 50.777344-81.4375 50.777344-124.742187 0-42.066407-14.425781-80.878907-40.617188-109.289063zm0 0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: edit the viewbox to give it more space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the `viewBox` attribute:

```
viewBox="-25 -53 562.00002 562"
```

Adds space for a `25px` margin.

Note that you have to decrease the top/left coordinates by 25 and increase the bottom/right coordinates by double the amount as your width/height must cater for 2 times the margin width.

```css
svg {
  width: 10rem;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #222;
  stroke-width: 30;
}

svg:hover {
  fill: #222;
}
```

```html
<svg 
  viewBox="-25 -53 562.00002 562" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
  <path d="m471.382812 44.578125c-26.503906-28.746094-62.871093-44.578125-102.410156-44.578125-29.554687 0-56.621094 9.34375-80.449218 27.769531-12.023438 9.300781-22.917969 20.679688-32.523438 33.960938-9.601562-13.277344-20.5-24.660157-32.527344-33.960938-23.824218-18.425781-50.890625-27.769531-80.445312-27.769531-39.539063 0-75.910156 15.832031-102.414063 44.578125-26.1875 28.410156-40.613281 67.222656-40.613281 109.292969 0 43.300781 16.136719 82.9375 50.78125 124.742187 30.992188 37.394531 75.535156 75.355469 127.117188 119.3125 17.613281 15.011719 37.578124 32.027344 58.308593 50.152344 5.476563 4.796875 12.503907 7.4375 19.792969 7.4375 7.285156 0 14.316406-2.640625 19.785156-7.429687 20.730469-18.128907 40.707032-35.152344 58.328125-50.171876 51.574219-43.949218 96.117188-81.90625 127.109375-119.304687 34.644532-41.800781 50.777344-81.4375 50.777344-124.742187 0-42.066407-14.425781-80.878907-40.617188-109.289063zm0 0"/>
</svg>
```